# Is action cable stateless on the servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

If I run rails 5 on multiple servers, like on elastic beanstalk, will things run fine in terms of action cable real-time features or will there be issues b/c rails holds some state on the servers?

If action cable is stateless on the server that I should be fine, I'm hoping all state is stored in redis.